# How to know decoration property needs "BoxDecoration"

Tags: flutter

I am a beginner in flutter so question may be very basic...
from where i can understand "Container" property "decoration" needs "BoxDecoration"
flutter official website saying "decoration" needs "Decoration" type. I am adding one image for better understanding..Thanks in advance [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDuUz.png)

Comment: `BoxDecoration` inherits the `Decoration` type. So, as far as `Container` is concerned, `BoxDecoration` is of type `Decoration`. You can and should use `BoxDecoration()` for a `Container`. `Decoration` is an abstract type, so you can never supply `Decoration()` as a value anyway.

Comment: have you look into the official docs? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html

Comment: thanks to all good explanation..

Answer (score 1):

The one we mostly use is `BoxDecoration`,
Example code:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: const Color(0xff7c94b6),
    image: const DecorationImage(
      image: NetworkImage('https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/owl-2.jpg'),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
    border: Border.all(
      color: Colors.black,
      width: 8,
    ),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
  ),
)
```

for more [api.flutter.dev](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, sometimes guessing this kind of thing without using the internet is hard in Flutter. But there are few cases like that. Don't worry. You'll learn them over time.